# How to view photos selected by PhotoPicker(android 13) in phone's gallery

Tags: uri, mediastore, photo-gallery, android-13, photo-picker

Android 13(sdk 33) has introduced a new PhotoPicker that provides a better way to let the user pick photos in apps but it has some limits.

Now it's possible to get the uri when you select a photo(or photos) but when I want to re-open that uri with `Intent.ACTION_VIEW` it doesn't work and only opens the google photos app and I have not been able to find a solution for this. The only thing that I found was [this link](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/243294058?pli=1) that explains that PhotoPicker URIs are different from other ones and there's a limited set of things that you can do with them. Also here's what [google document](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore#ACTION_PICK_IMAGES) says if it add any more context:

> Specifically, picker URIs can only be opened for read and queried for
> columns in PickerMediaColumns

So I need to know if there's a way to open a photo in photo gallery useing PhotoPicker uri or if it's entirely impossible. I'll be glad if you share your thoughts.